# Регулярные выражения. Добавить символ в начало и конец строки

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var replaced_element = document.getElementsByClassName("translate-price");
  for (var i = 0; i < replaced_element.length; i++) {
    replaced_element[i].innerHTML = replaced_element[i].innerHTML.replace(new RegExp("[0-9]", 'g'), "<span>Здесь должно быть найденное число</span>");
  }
}
```

Необходимо ко всем найденным числам добавить перед числом открывающий тег span и после числа закрывающий тег span. Нужно как-то подставить в замену найденное число, но не могу понять как. Буду благодарен за любую помощь)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В заменяемой строке можно использовать ссылку `$&`. Тогда эта ссылка заменится на найденную строку.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var replaced_element = document.getElementsByClassName("translate-price");
  for (var i = 0; i < replaced_element.length; i++) {
    replaced_element[i].innerHTML = replaced_element[i].innerHTML.replace(/\d+/g, "<span>$&</span>");
  }
}
```

```css
span {
  color: blue;
 }
```

```html
<div class="translate-price">Цена: 500USD</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var el = document.querySelector("main")
el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/-?\d+/g, "<span>$&</span>")
```

```css
span { color: red }
```

```html
<main>Необходимо ко -1 всем найденным числам 789 добавить перед числом -789 открывающий тег span и после числа закрывающий тег span. Нужно как-то 456 подставить в замену найденное число, но не могу понять 99645646 5456 как. Буду благодарен 4564564 за любую помощь)</main>
```